# Getting 960.gs to work in IE6 - Please assist

Tags: internet-explorer-6, 960.gs

I'm using the 960.gs grid system to style a website. It appears fine in all the major browsers, except in IE6, I see other sites using the 960.gs perfectly well and it displaying fine in IE6 and wanted to know what I need to tweak to appear correctly.

Here's more info on the 960.gs system: http://960.gs

I've used the class="grid_6 omega" to try and force my last div to float to the right. Which it does in all browsers except IE6. Does anyone know what I need to do to make it work in IE6, do I need to clear something?

Any advice greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the problem this morning for anyone wanting to know. I'm using 960.gs and Thematic because I think they're both brilliant in their own ways.

The solution that worked for me was to add the following CSS styling to the containing `div` **before** the `div` that floats to the right, in my case this DIV happens to be called `leftloopcontainer`, but obviously adjust it to whatever you need it to be:

```
#leftloopcontainer {overflow: hidden; zoom: 1;}
```

After I did this IE6 behaved (well, as much as that troublesome browser can!) and displayed my content just fine!